# Ninject Inject Common DbContext Into Numerous Repositories

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

There’s something which I am doing that is working, but I think it can probably be done a lot better (and therefore, with more maintainability).

I am using Ninject to inject various things into a controller. The problem which I needed to solve is that the DbContext for each repository needed to be the same. That is, the same object in memory.

Whilst, the following code does achieve that, my Ninject *common config file* has started to get quite messy as I have to write similar code for each controller:

```
kernel.Bind<OrderController>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    var sharedContext = ctx.Kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>();
    var userAccountService = kernel.Get<UserAccountService>();
    ILogger logger = new Log4NetLogger(typeof(Nml.OrderController));
    ILogger loggerForOrderManagementService = new Log4NetLogger(typeof(OrderManagementService));


    var orderManagementService = new OrderManagementService(
        new AffiliateRepository(sharedContext),
        new RegTypeRepository(sharedContext),
        new OrderRepository(sharedContext),
        new RefDataRepository(),
        new WebUserRepository(sharedContext),
        new WebinarRepository(sharedContext),
        loggerForOrderManagementService,
        ttsConfig
        );

    var membershipService = new MembershipService(
        new InstitutionRepository(sharedContext),
        new RefDataRepository(),
        new SamAuthenticationService(userAccountService),
        userAccountService,
        new WebUserRepository(sharedContext)
        );

    return new OrderController(membershipService, orderManagementService, kernel.Get<IStateService>(), logger);
}).InRequestScope();
```

Is there a neater way of doing this?

**Edit**

Tried the following code. As soon as I make a second request, an exception is chucked that the DbContext has already been disposed.

```
kernel.Bind<TTSWebinarsContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

string baseUrl = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
kernel.Bind<IStateService>().To<StateService>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IRefDataRepository>().To<RefDataRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>()); 

var config = MembershipRebootConfig.Create(baseUrl, kernel.Get<IStateService>(), kernel.Get<IRefDataRepository>());
var ttsConfig = TtsConfig.Create(baseUrl);

kernel.Bind<MembershipRebootConfiguration>().ToConstant(config);
kernel.Bind<TtsConfiguration>().ToConstant(ttsConfig);

kernel.Bind<IAffiliateRepository>().To<AffiliateRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>());
kernel.Bind<IWebinarRepository>().To<WebinarRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>());
kernel.Bind<IWebUserRepository>().To<WebUserRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>());
kernel.Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<OrderRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>());
kernel.Bind<IInstitutionRepository>().To<InstitutionRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>());
kernel.Bind<IUserAccountRepository>().To<DefaultUserAccountRepository>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IRegTypeRepository>().To<RegTypeRepository>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<TTSWebinarsContext>());

kernel.Bind<UserAccountService>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    var userAccountService = new UserAccountService(config, ctx.Kernel.Get<IUserAccountRepository>());
    return userAccountService;
});

kernel.Bind<IOrderManagementService>().To<OrderManagementService>().InRequestScope();

//RegisterControllers(kernel, ttsConfig);

kernel.Bind<AuthenticationService>().To<SamAuthenticationService>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IMembershipService>().To<MembershipService>().InRequestScope();
```

There's something about InRequestScope I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
`.InRequestScope()` will ensure everything which gets injected *that*  binding will receive exactly the same instance when during injection (creation) the `HttpContext.Current` is the same. That means when a client makes a request and the kernel is asked to provide instances with `.InRequestScope()`, it will return the same instance for the exact same request. Now when a client makes another request, another unique instance will be created.
When the request ends, ninject will dispose the instance in case it implements `IDisposable`.

**However** consider the following scenario:

```
public class A
{
  private readonly DbContext dbContext;

  public A(DbContext dbContext)
  {
      this.dbContext = dbContext;
  }
 }
```

and binding:

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
IBindingRoot.Bind<A>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

You got yourself a major problem. There's two scenarios how this can pan out:

1. You are trying to create an `A` outside of a request. It will fail. Instantiating the `DbContext`, ninject will look for HttpContext.Current - which is null at the time - and throw an Exception.
2. You are trying to create an `A` during a request. Instantiating will succeed. However, When you try to use some functionality of `A` (which is accessing `DbContext` in turn) after the request or during a new request, it will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`

To sum it up, an `ObjectDisposedException` when you access the `DbContext` can *only* be caused by two scenarios:
-you ar disposing the `DbContext` (or some component which in turn disposes the `DbContext`) before the request is over. 
-you are keeping a reference to the `DbContext` (again, or to some component which in turn references the `DbContext`) across request boundaries.

That's it. Nothing complicated about this, but your object graph.

So what would help is drawing an object graph. Start from the root / request root. Then when you're done, start from the `DbContext` and check who's calling `Dispose()` on it. If there is no usage inside your code, it must be Ninject who's cleaning up when the request ends. That means, you need to check all references to the `DbContext`. Someone is keeping a reference across requests.

Original Answer:
You should look into scopes: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes
Specifically, `.InRequestScope()` - or in case that is not appliccable to your problem - `.InCallScope()` should be interesting to you.

As you are already using `.InRequestScope()` for the original binding, i suggest that binding the shared context type also `.InRequestScope()` should be sufficient. It means every dependency of the `OrderController` will receive the same webinar context instance. Furthermore, if someone else in the same request wants to get a webinar context injected, he will also get the same instance.

You should look into scopes: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes
Specifically, `.InRequestScope()` - or in case that is not appliccable to your problem - `.InCallScope()` should be interesting to you.

As you are already using `.InRequestScope()` for the original binding, i suggest that binding the shared context type also `.InRequestScope()` should be sufficient. It means every dependency of the `OrderController` will receive the same webinar context instance. Furthermore, if someone else in the same request wants to get a webinar context injected, he will also get the same instance.

Comment: Thanks. I remember I had problems with the context being disposed because I would be calling methods on a WebApi controller. The closures in the above code solved that for me. But I'm left wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get what you're trying to say. You don't want to dispose the webinar context when the request is over? The context does not to exist longer than the request/the OrderController? What is the problem _exactly_ when you bind the webinar context `.InRequestScope()`?

Comment: I'm going on memory here, because I "solved" the problem a while back. The shared context was being disposed of too early. But possibly that is because I was sharing it across requests. I'll take another run at it soon to see if I can get the scopes correct. Might take a couple of days. Wearing many hats right now.

Comment: I get the exception DbContext has been disposed. Please see edit part of the question for the code.

Comment: hmmm. OK. It's a complex scenario. I want every DbContext injected into each Repository in each service to be the same object in memory. But it burns me across requests. As my original solution solves it (and it is easy to see why), I think I'll chuck this back on the low priority stack. Thanks. Answer awarded either way.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: So you want every `DbContext` (is there more than one? Are some classes inheriting from `DbContext`? i don't know EF that well) to be Singleton? If you want to have that, you can just bind them `.InSingletonScope()`...

Comment: Can you fix this , I also set a bounty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146873/dbcontext-with-ninject-ado-net/